# Improve scroll performance with time profiler iOS

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, instruments, profiler

Im looking for ways to improve tableView scroll performance. All resources have pointed at using the time profiler. Now after I have gotten results I'm having difficulty understanding how to identify bottle necks.

Since I'm looking at the main thread, is the solution to **find bottle necks and move them off to other worker threads?** Also, each tableview cell contains an image and a collectionView that can have up to 4 images downloaded. Is this a performance hit in itself?

**Id appreciate any tips on how to find insights from time profiler and improve scroll performance.**
Below I took screenshots of the main areas I thought I should focus (even though there is a worker thread with a 24% weight).

**CFRunLoopDoObservers** 
One resource pointed out how I can move image decoding off of the main thread.(highlighted). 
[image]

**CFRunLoopDoSource1** Highlighted area has high weight, but looks like scrolling stuff, which is in fact what is happening. Smooth scroll method also makes me think someone has already tried to optimize already. 
[image]

**CFRunLoopDoSource0** 
[image]